# How use script type="text/x-template" with multilanguage?

Tags: html, asp.net, vue.js, keyboard, monitor

I use ASP NET with VueJS. ASP NET render view component:

```
<script type="text/x-template" id="form-template">
    @if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.LastName))
    {
        <input asp-for="LastName" class="form-control" maxlength="100" autofocus required />
    }
    else
    {
        <input asp-for="LastName" class="form-control" maxlength="100" required />
    }
</script>
```

My action on C#:

```
    public async Task<ActionResult<ViewComponent>> GetAdditionalFormRegistrationComponentAsync()
    {
            var customerViewModel = new CustomerAdditionFormViewModel
            {                    
                LastName = "русские символы"
            };

            return ViewComponent("FormRegistration", customerViewModel);
        }
    }
```

ViewComponent:

```
    public Task<IViewComponentResult> InvokeAsync(CustomerAdditionFormViewModel customerViewModel)
    {
        return Task.Run<IViewComponentResult>(() => View(customerViewModel));
    }
```

LastName write in English input value OK. But if LastName fill in russian I get:

[image]

How fix this?

Comment: Why is this tagged with vue/javascript?

Comment: @evolutionxbox because I use vue in this template. I think my problem use type="text/x-template"

Comment: May you update the question so the code is a runnable [mcve]?

Comment: @evolutionxbox I updated

Comment: Good. Hopefully that will be enough to encourage answers.

Comment: @Viktor, you could as well tag it with `keyboard` or `monitor` since you're using them to see your website. Javascript and/or Vue experts can help you about as much as keyboard and monitor experts can help you. Your issue boils down to how your backend serves the page. At most you could tag it with `html`, as it likely has to do with html encoding.

Answer (score 1):

I have found solution.
Need add Html.Raw()

```
<input value=“@Html.Raw(Model.LastName)" class="form-control" maxlength="100" autofocus required />
```

or

```
services.AddWebEncoders(options =>
{
    options.TextEncoderSettings = new TextEncoderSettings();
    options.TextEncoderSettings.AllowRange(UnicodeRanges.All);
});
```